# Why is this string comparation not working?

Tags: bash, if-statement, comparison, double-quotes

I'm trying to compare a md5 hash with one saved in a file, the result is that always the hashes are unqual, even when they are equal:

```
#!/bin/bash

checksum=$(ls <FOLDER> | md5sum)
last_checksum=$(cat CHECKSUM)

if [ "$checksum" != "$last_checksum" ]; then
    echo -n $checksum > CHECKSUM
    echo CHECKSUMS ARE UNEQUAL
fi
```

printing both checksums are equal.

Comment: Adding a `printf '%q\n' "$checksum" "$last_checksum"` before your *if* statement could help you find the difference. At first glace it seem to be correct. Also I would prefer to not use `echo -n` here. Text files tend to work better when they end with anewline.

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `echo -n $checksum` does not preserve the double space between the hash value and the filename, `-`, which means that if `$checksum` contains

```
49a6b6e584f20a28509c1da3c311cda6  -
```

Then what will be written to the file will instead be

```
49a6b6e584f20a28509c1da3c311cda6 -
```

Quotes will help to preseve the original string:

```bash
echo -n "$checksum" > CHECKSUM
```

---

You could also remove the filename part of the checksum since that's not interesting:

```
checksum=$(ls . | md5sum | cut -d' ' -f1)
```